# How to use Apollo/Graphql hooks within external React.js component library

Tags: reactjs, shared-libraries, apollo, apollo-client

I have 3 React.js projects and I'm trying to consolidate the reused components across all 3 projects into one shared component library.

This component library is hosted on Github and imported into all 3 projects through the `package.json` file like this:

```
"components": "github:myusername/components"`
```

I am then able to import the components from the library into each project like such:

```
import { Form } from "components"
```

but when the component being imported (in this case a `Form`) uses an Apollo/Graphql hook (`useQuery`, or `useMutation`) I get this error:

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.`

I've found countless questions about this same error, but the solutions are either already in place or irrelevant. Here is what I've found so far:

1. Wrap the App with the `<ApolloProvider client={client}>` tag (this is already there in the 3 projects - but not in the "components" library)
2. use the `@apollo/client` package instead of the `@apollo/react-hooks` - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905153/react-apollo-could-not-find-client-in-the-context-or-passed-in-as-an-option) (already using that package)

Comment: have you found any solutions for this so far?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to define `@apollo/client` as a peer dependency in the root `package.json` of my shared lirbary (I'm using lerna).

It didn't work for me to just link the package with `yarn link` but I had to publish it on npm.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a little more given Kn3cht's information that the shared component works if published to NPM and found a beautiful solution.  There is a utility called [yalc](https://github.com/wclr/yalc) that works perfectly.  The problem with npm/yarn link is that symlinked dependencies are not deduped.  To use, install yalc globally (eg, npm install yalc --global or yarn global add yalc).

Let's say the component to be shared is called *shared-component*.

1. In the root folder of shared_component, type 'yalc push'.
2. In the root folder of component that will import the shared_component, type 'yalc link shared-component'

That's it.  I can't believe this utility is not more widely known.  I believe you still need to designate react and apollo dependencies as peerDependencies in package.json.

As for Lerna, there is a small wiring needed to have updates automatically pushed whenever the shared-component changes.  Essentially, install [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) at the root of the mono repo as a dev dependency, then add scripts to the root and all component package.json files that you want to have automatically pushed.  For example, the target I create is called "watch:push".  In the root package.json:

```js
"scripts": {
    "watch:push": "lerna run watch:push"  
}
```

For each component that I want to share I add this target to its package.json:

```js
"scripts": {
    "push": "yalc push",
    "watch:push": "watch 'yarn push' ./dist",
}
```

Here you can manually push your shared-component via *yarn push*, or you can have the shared-component pushed whenever the contents of the build folder have changed (in my case the folder is dist).

So to make this fully automatic, you need to run run a command separately that executes a build whenever source code changes.